# Obtain props of Contacts with component react-native-contacts

Tags: react-native

My english is bad, but I will try explain my problem.

I have obtain the prop givenName of contacts in React Native Android. I installed the component react-native-contacts and use the next code to print with console.log() the name of only contact:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';
...
class myComponent extends Component {
...
 render() {
  Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
   console.log(typeof err + err);
   if(err === 'denied'){
    // x.x
   } else {
    console.log(contacts);
    console.log("Nombre de contacto: " + contacts[0].givenName);
   }
  })
  return (
   <Container>
    ...
    <View>
      <Text>{}</Text>
    </View>
   </Container>
  );
 }
}
```

So, i need to print the name of the contact in  {} . I have tried to get it as if it were a flat object. Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

You should move your code out of render and use state

```
componentWillMount() {
  Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
    console.log(typeof err + err);
    if(err === 'denied'){
    // x.x
    } else {
      console.log(contacts);
      console.log("Nombre de contacto: " + contacts[0].givenName);
      this.setState({contacts}); 
   }
  })
}
```

then your render() will be like

```
<View>
  <Text>{this.state.contacts[0].givenName}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your proposal, but running the project shows: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to render it before Contacts.getAll() returns, a null check for state.contacts should prob work?

Comment: Ok, if check state.contacts == null, shows false in console. So, the state does not arriving to <text>{...}</text> ?

Comment: How about trying a JSON.stringify() on contacts? {} (empty object) is not null